# XML parsing in linux, print multiple elements

Tags: php, xml, linux, bash, rss

So I found a script online for xml parsing in linux that I am wanting to use, and I was hoping to get some help with understanding how the script works, and how to edit it for my own use.

Here is the script ([credit](http://6502cpu.blogspot.com/2012/03/rss-news-headlines-prompter-update.html))

```
#!/bin/bash

cat $1 | awk '

START {    pos=1;    xml=$0    len=length(xml);    endp=1 }

{    while(pos <= len)    {
      if(substr(xml,pos,7) == "<title>")
      {
         pos=pos+7;
         endp=pos;
         while((substr(xml,endp,8) != "</title>") && (endp < len))
         {
            endp++;
         }
         print "   ",substr(xml,pos,endp-pos)," * ";
         pos=endp+7;
      }
      pos++;    } }'
```

[Here](http://pastie.org/4397264) is a simplified sample of the xml data I will be using

I have already gotten rid of the extra characters on both sides of the  tags and made a few other adjustments by changing the script to this

```
  #!/bin/bash

    cat $1 | awk '

    START {    pos=1;    xml=$0    len=length(xml);    endp=1 }

    {    while(pos <= len)    {
          if(substr(xml,pos,16) == "<sport><![CDATA[")
          {
             pos=pos+16;
             endp=pos;
             while((substr(xml,endp,11) != "]]></sport>") && (endp < len))
             {
                endp++;
             }
             print "",substr(xml,pos,endp-pos),"";
             pos=endp+10;
          }
          pos++;    } }'
```

So using this script leaves me with a plain text file with this result

```
Women's Soccer
Men's Soccer
Women's Soccer
```

Ultimately I'd like to have a script output the following

```
Women's Soccer Away @ South Carolina (Exhibition) at 7:00 PM
Men's Soccer Home vs. Ohio State at 7:00 PM
Women's Soccer Away @ William and Mary at 7:00 PM
```

For those wondering, this is the shell that calls the parse script (ignore file names and locations)

```
wget -O rss.xml http://en-us.fxfeeds.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/headlines.xml
        ~dsl/bin/rssparse! rss.xml > headlines_$$.tmp
        cd /tmp/ldmtrx
        split --lines=30 /tmp/headlines_$$.tmp ldmtrxnews
        cd /tmp
        rm headlines_$$.tmp rss.xml
```

While it would be greatly appreciated, I don't expect anyone to complete this task for me, I'd just really like some tips and help getting started.  I'm not sure how to run this script on a different element and then print both elements (for example `<sport>` and `<homeaway>`)  I could run the script again, but then the elements would be printed on different lines.

Lastly, I'd like to know how to exclude all data that does not have a `<date>` matching today's date.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't get the "label" on the block with 'START', typically it is 'BEGIN', indicating this block of code is processed at the BEGINing, before any input files are processed. What you have here a a very typical awk script. You should be able to figure it out by reading an awk tutorial or two. Try http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html for starters. Consider editing your question to show us the date format you want to exclude. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, haha knowing what kind of script it is definitely will help.  And the date format would be mm/dd/YYYY.  Is there anyway to get the current date from the awk script if the script is called from bash?

Comment: inside the BEGIN block add `"date +%m/%d/%Y" | getline myDate;` and then use `myDate` for your comparisons with something like `if (myDate == $2) { .... stuff } ; else { not date stuff ...}`. Read about `awk`'s concept of numbered fields, which use `$0` for the whole line, `$1` for the first field, `$2` = 2nd fld, etc, with `$NF` = last field on line. Again, consider editing your question to include all questions and information you have, so responders don't have to read thru a long chain of comments. Good luck.

Comment: Finally, given that it looks like you're trying to work with data about the Olympics, time must be of essence. So you'll really do better finding out about tools that are xml specific. Look here for xmlstarlet. Or consider posting a clear sample of expected input, required output and attach a 50 point bounty. You should get some good answers quickly. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, I just did that.  I think I'd rather spend my time learning xmlstarlet, since it was designed for xml data.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know that your example lacks of validation. It needs some tweaks

check [this pastie](http://pastie.org/pastes/4408130/download) instead of [that pastie](http://pastie.org/pastes/4397264/download)

then using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s01.html) you can superseed all that this script does.

```
$ wget --output-document - http://pastie.org/pastes/4408130/download | xmlstarlet sel -t -m rss/channel/item -v sport -o ' Away @ ' -v opponent -o ' at ' -v time -na
```

That outputs:

```
Women's Soccer Away @ South Carolina (Exhibition) at 7:00 PM
Men's Soccer Away @ Ohio State (Exhibition) at 7:00 PM
Women's Soccer Away @ William and Mary at 7:00 PM
```

And when the output is what you need you can use **-C** with xmlstarlet to show an xml template you can source in any language you need that particular parsing.